# Angular loading img src in repeater without items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular repeater (table) which includes a src element. However, my URL gets called the first time before the items are loaded, causing one 404 load like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/%7B%7Bitem.obj.thumbnailurl%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

The table looks like this (simplified):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item title</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>{{item.obj.itemtitle}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{item.obj.landingpageurl}}">
                    <img src="{{item.obj.thumbnailurl}}"/>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The *items* array is loaded later, as a result of a search.

What happens is each time I open this view (even without page reloads, just opening other views) I get that 404 error.

Why is that happening? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As CodeHater suggests, using `ng-src` will solve this issue. The problem is that the browser interprets `{{item.obj.thumbnailurl}}` as a real `src` attribute before angular has compiled the `ng-repeat` and its contents. This is also the reason why you get exactly one such error even though the `img` tag is inside a `ng-repeat`. When using `ng-src`, angular will insert the correct `src` attribute in your DOM the moment it compiles the `ng-repeat` and its contents.

Comment: Hmm, I changed this on another table (another view) but now I get this: http://localhost:9000/null :( I guess I should put filtered result instead of orig there?

Comment: Well, apparently item.obj.thumbnailurl evaluates to null. Hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the code or the data.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is browsers load images immediately when the tag is parsed which is before angular has a chance to replace it with dynamic value. Try [ng-src](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc) to fix that. The same holds true for `href`, to avoid the user clicking it before Angular has a chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value, try [ng-href](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref)

Answer (score 1):

As guys here mentioned, `ng-src` fixes this problem.
Anyway if you are changing the image source dynamically, be sure to define the default value for a better UX to show some loader image before the code defines the real image.